# Where to store an array

Tags: ios, arrays

This is a question that requires a general answer so I'm not going to include any code. If I have an array that stores images and a specific image is displayed depending on the direction I move my finger, is it good practice to store the array in the viewController where all of the touch logic is located, or do I create a new class and store it there?

Comment: iOS is based on the MVC pattern and it's never to early to start practicing it. If you were following the MVC pattern the array would be in the model. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of the documentation and its contents, but I was confused by the array considering that my touch logic could directly access the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning on reusing the array from other classes (for example from other view controllers)? If the answer is yes, you should probably create a new class to store that array. Otherwise you should be fine by keeping it in the view controller that is going to use it.

Comment: I want to get used to good programming practices so I think I will create a separate class and go with that considering that I will add more than one type of array to it.